# Make a trailing newline execute a command when pasted into the shell

Tags: bash, shell, readline

A couple of months ago, a system update caused my shell to no longer interpret trailing newlines as an <kbd>enter</kbd> when pasting a command into the terminal. For example, if I write `ls` at my prompt and then use my mouse to select the `ls` until the end of the line, I expect that I can then middle-click paste into a shell and have the `ls` command executed. This is standard behavior which I have been using for years.

However, my system no longer does that. I can paste the `ls`, and I can see the newline was also pasted because my cursor moves to the next line, but despite this, the command isn't executed until I press  <kbd>enter</kbd> (I am putting this in a spoiler because it is an animated gif and can be distracting):

> [image: animated gif showing the effect described]

In the animation above, you can see me selecting a line with `ls` already written, then clearing the `ls` and middle-click pasting. Note how the cursor moves to the next line, but the `ls` command isn't executed at that point, but only after I hit my <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

The really strange thing, for me, is that this isn't an issue with my terminal emulator (`terminator`). The very same terminal will interpret the newline as expected if I ssh into a different machine (but not if I ssh into localhost). So it has to be some sort of setting in my local shell.

Also, there is one context where it does work as expected: the `read` builtin. Here, if I select a line including the trailing newline, I can paste it into a waiting `read` prompt and the trailing newline is taken as the EOL character, making `read` return. So why doesn't it work outside that specific context?

All of this is on an Arch Linux system, using `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` in `emacs` mode. To make matters even more confusing, I have this issue when using `bash`, `zsh` or `fish`, but not when using `ksh`, `dash`, `tcsh` or `csh`. In the latter four shells, I have my desired behavior and the pasted line is immediately executed. Could this be related to `readline`?

How can I get my desired behavior back and have any newlines pasted into my shell be interpreted?

Comment: Happens with Cygwin `bash` too. Line editing is `vi` mode. Relatively recently. Looking forward to an answer here, but I would suggest that it is indeed a `readline` change

Comment: @roaima I take it you haven't found a workaround, right? I only realized today, while writing this up, that it affects multiple and yet not all shells on my system which was particularly confusing. My line editing is set to `emacs` mode, in bash at least.

Comment: Getting a second data point (i.e. yours for me, or (presumably) mine for you) enabled the discovery

Comment: @Quasímodo not really, no. I _want_ the behavior that the other question is trying to avoid. Sure, you can maybe guess that setting the same setting to `off` (which isn't mentioned there) might help, but the questions are diametrically opposed with one asking "how can I NOT do foo" and the other asking "how can I DO foo?". Also, the dupe does not address what changed which roaima explains nicely.

Comment: @Quasímodo yes, exactly. Also, this is me with my regular user hat on, not my mod hat on. If the community feels it is a dupe, I will not object. I just honestly think it isn't and that the next person with the same question would need to see _this_ answer instead of the dupe. I am trying to be impartial here, but of course that isn't really possible since it's my question, so I will happily abide with whatever the community decides.

Comment: @terdon (with your *regular* - emphasis on "regular" -  user hat still on you) - this is something I'd ***STRONGLY*** recommend against doing. The one time that this will prevent your from accidentally running a broken/dangerous command will mean that all the times you were mildly inconvenienced by having to press enter will be paid over.

Comment: I think @muru's point is worth emphasizing; I use the command line a lot, including copy/pasting text (which may be commands). Newlines included in the paste would often run a command before I had the chance to finetune it, and an incorrect paste could really mess things up. This has caused actual damage for me more than once. It took a bit of effort to get used to the new behaviour, but now I much prefer it.

Comment: @muru I would rather risk the malicious command. I very regularly need to copy/paste commands from my Readme files to reproduce things, and very often need to paste multiple commands that need to run sequentially, and having to switch from "mouse mode" to "keyboard mode" is incredibly annoying. On the other hand, I very rarely copy/paste commands from the internet so the chances of my having a malicious command in my clipboard are minimal. The annoyance far outweighs the risk for me. I check my commands before pasting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The behaviour change is captured in this "Not a bug" report with RedHat https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1954366, which references the `readline` setting `enable-bracketed-paste`:

> Add `set enable-bracketed-paste Off` to the `.inputrc` fixes it. But it shouldn't have been broken in the first place.

Indeed, adding this setting to `~/.inputrc` resolves the issue: pasting an embedded newline executes the pasted command once more.

References

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1954366
- [bracketed paste mode](https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste) -
  Conrad Irwin, April 2013

**Please note that a number of experienced users both here and elsewhere strongly warn users against this.** For example, [@muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) writes [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/689394/make-a-trailing-newline-execute-a-command-when-pasted-into-the-shell/689399#comment1303741_689394) that, "*this is something I'd STRONGLY recommend against doing. The one time that this will prevent you from accidentally running a broken/dangerous command will mean that all the times you were mildly inconvenienced by having to press enter will be paid over.*"

Comment: YESH! Thank you so much, this has been driving me up the wall for a while now! I guess I now need a follow-up question to understand why this affected only that specific set of shells. Presumably, these are the shells that read the `~/.inputrc` file or that use `readline` or something.

Comment: Allegedly enabled by default from `bash` version 5.1 but I'm finding it enabled in 4.4.12(3)

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Please add to your answer that one needs to start a new `bash` session for this change to take effect. Pasting this into existing `bash` prompt doesn't change anything. Thank you!

Comment: @stason I'm pleased you have a solution to something that's been bothering you. Restarting the shell is a usual requirement when changing a configuration file

Comment: I use wezterm with bash on macOS and I have the exact opposite problem. Pasting code with new lines will run the commands immediately. I don't want that. I tried `set enable-bracketed-paste on` in the `.inputrc`, but it doesn't work. What can I do, please?

Comment: @MartinBraun I'd suggest you write a new question, referencing this one and explaining how you've tried to set up the reverse situation

Comment: @ChrisDavies Thanks, I investigated further. The issue was only present in the login shell, because `/bin/bash` is too old and I was fooled by `bash --version`, because it is linked to `/usr/local/bin/bash`, a much newer `bash` that I installed via `brew install bash` in the past. The solution is to append `/usr/local/bin/bash` onto `/etc/shells` and then `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash` and now the feature is available in all shells, including the login shell.