# Pasting multiple commands from clipboard breaks after a sudo command

Tags: bash, clipboard

I have 2 CentOS systems which I connect to via ssh.
On one of them if I paste multiple commands from the clipboard, it executes them all, unless there's a sudo command in there. If there is, it just does it, and skips all other commands.
Eg.:

```
$ echo aa
sudo echo bb
echo cc
```

Results:

```
aa
bb
```

Doesn't matter which sudo command, doesn't matter how many commands before or after.
`bind -v`'s `enable-bracketed-paste` is set to `off`

Another example:

```
$ sudo echo dd ;\
echo ee
echo ff
```

Result:

```
dd
ee
```

Other CentOS, it doesn't happen.
Why does it happen and how to fix w/o modifying the pasted command?

**EDIT**: discovered that on `ksh` it does not happen. I can't install other shells to test.

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: xterm on both systems. I'm using a windows PuTTY or MobaXterm to connect. New discovery - using ksh, it doesn't happen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a trailing newline execute a command when pasted into the shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/689394/100397)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. `enable-bracketed-paste` is already `Off`

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour on Bash 5.1.16, Readline 8.01, but only when using Screen (v4.09). It does not happen in a non-screen shell or ssh session, and the behaviour is the same regardless of the `enable-bracketed-paste` setting.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a case of standard input inadvertent consuming.

Anything you paste in an interactive session is standard input data available to the command running in the foreground at that moment, and is normally shared by (and available to) all and any command you may be running in sequence, however quickly (or slowly) you may be able to type/paste. Each of the commands has its chance to consume part or all of the standard input data that happens to be available at the time of its execution.

`sudo` is indeed one of those commands that will actively *eat up* **all** its standard input **if** it is configured to do so, which may well be the case for security reasons especially in enterprise setups. If this is the case for you, `sudo` is consuming whatever text (i.e. the subsequent commands) you have pasted in.

If you are allowed to see the `/etc/sudoers*` file(s) of the host you're experiencing that behavior on, check them whether they possibly have a `Defaults` line setting either `use_pty` or `log_input` (or even both), for `ALL`, or perhaps for your account or group, or even just for that exact command you're running through `sudo`. As a matter of fact, it may actually even be some other system-wide plugin set in `/etc/sudo.conf`, if the system administrator has been so inclined (unlikely, but possible).

---

Anyhow, you should be able to work-around that behavior by simply wrapping your paste within a sub-shell:

Just start by typing an open parentheses <kbd>(</kbd> at the regular prompt of whatever shell you're using, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You'll see the so-called "PS2" (aka "more input needed") prompt, which typically is `>` , where you can keep typing commands at will and, of course, also pasting them from your clipboard just as they are. These commands will not be run immediately, they will rather be "enqueued" in the sub-shell started by the open parentheses until you end it explicitly. When you're done typing/pasting, finish by typing the close parentheses <kbd>)</kbd> and again <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which ends the sub-shell.

Only at that point will your pasted commands finally run, without being "eaten up" by any one of them in midst (`sudo` or else) that might be consuming standard input as per its normal (or special) behavior. This is because all your relevant standard input (i.e. your pasting) will have already been consumed by the "enqueuing" sub-shell and thus `sudo` will have nothing to "eat up".

---

Note finally that in your case `enable-bracketed-paste on` *would* be your friend, as that essentially makes `bash` detect *pasted* text, differentiating it from *typed* text, aided by the terminal emulator (as long as the terminal emulator does offer such feature).

As to the reason why `ksh` seems to be working "correctly", I haven't delved into its internals but, at a first glance of `strace`-ing it, it appears to be reading *bufferfuls* of standard input, probably tokenizing it into single commands to run one by one, as opposed to reading-and-executing standard input in the typical streamlined fashion.

As to `screen` disregarding `enable-bracketed-paste on` altogether, I'm not an avid user of `screen` myself, but I can tell as much: it's clearly a very "rich" piece of software terminal-wise, it may *act* as a terminal emulator itself, and as such it might interfere with (e.g. ignore and strip away) the escape-codes that `bash` sends/receives to/from the terminal emulator for the bracketed-paste feature.

Comment: (1) "If you are allowed to see the `/etc/sudoers*` file(s) …" – Even if not, `sudo -l` or `sudo -ll` may reveal something. (2) In my Kubuntu I'm able to replicate the problem by manipulating `use_pty` in `sudoers` and `enable-bracketed-paste` in readline in Bash. I cannot tell if your diagnosis is exactly what happens in the OP's case, but I think it certainly is a possibility. +1 from me.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I had forgotten about those two user-oriented options

Answer (score 0):

This behavior may be related to how the shell is interpreting the command sequence when you paste it into the terminal. One possible explanation is that the shell on the system where this behavior is observed is interpreting the entire command sequence as a single line, and the `sudo` command is causing the shell to exit before executing the rest of the commands.

To avoid modifying the pasted command and work around this issue, you could try a couple of things:

1. Use a different shell: As you mentioned, the issue is not observed when using the Korn shell (ksh). You could try using a different shell, such as Bash or Zsh, to see if the behavior changes.
2. Use a subshell: You can group the commands in a subshell, and then use `sudo` to execute the subshell. This would ensure that all the commands are executed within the subshell, regardless of whether the `sudo` command exits the shell. For example:

```
$ (echo aa ; echo bb ; echo cc)
$ sudo sh -c '(echo aa ; echo bb ; echo cc)'
```

Note that the subshell approach may not work in all cases, especially if the pasted commands contain complex syntax or variable expansion.

If neither of these approaches work, you may need to modify the pasted command to ensure that the commands are executed in the correct order. For example, you could break up the command sequence into multiple lines, or use a shell script to execute the commands in the desired order.

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess that there is something in you shell's `readline`, your `PS1` prompt, or the `PROMPT_COMMAND` that discards pending characters from *stdin*.

Try typing these two lines *without waiting for the first to complete*:

```
sleep 10
id
```

If the `id` does not execute then you need to investigate the environment more closely.